# vue interpolation inside of my image tag as src:" {{ image }}"

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to dynamically pass an image url to my vue application but it seems not to be working so now i am wondering if its even possible to do so.. Yes, Please let me know if this is possible in Vue / Vuetify

```html
<v-img
  class="white--text align-end"
  height="200px"
  src="{{ book.imageUrl }}"
>
```

Comment: See also https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, just there is an error on your syntax.

suppose to use :src=  instead of just normal src

```
:src="book.imageUrl"
```

> colon in front of the attribute allow framework to see it as working code.

> non colon will result the "{{ book.imageUrl }}" as normal string only

Comment: No, that does not work. I get an error

Comment: sorry got correction

Comment: @KarinaTurtle without the {{ }}

Comment: Did as well and nothing

Comment: @KarinaTurtle could you check if your book.imageUrl image source exist in your folder ?

Comment: @KarinaTurtle what error?

Comment: @Phil "[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token '{' in

    {{

  Raw expression: :src='{{'

Comment: @kurtChun its coming from an API

Comment: @KarinaTurtle do try to console.log that imageUrl data, then paste the url on chrome new tab, see if the image existed or not

Answer (score 1):

You should use `require()` to your image urls, as suggested by KaelWD in this [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5403#issuecomment-432501042).

```html
<v-img
  class="white--text align-end"
  height="200px"
  :src="require(`${book.imageUrl}`)"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
:src="book.imageUrl"
```

I think you can't use {{var}} to pass a variable to attribute of Vue component

Comment: No this gives me an error..

Comment: show me the error. I think you are having another issue, it's not about image component with dynamic link :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in a project

```
:src="require('../../assets/img/logos/' + vendor.vendor_identifier + '.png')"
```

Webpack needs you to restrict the amount of possible files by giving it a part of the path as a literal string, at least - or the whole path, in the best case.

Relevant docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

So the method everyone mentioned is basically correct but you just have add half the path inside the `require('../../assets/img/logos/')`  . Also can you show what you are sending in `{{book.imageUrl}}` ?

First I would hard code the link/path sent in `book.imageUrl` and see if the error exists

Comment: its coming from an api

Comment: Can you console.log(book.imageUrl) to see what the link looks like?